# [UIImageAsset retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimageasset

A line

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient-image"];
```

gets executed inside an NSOperation, on the background thread.
The code breaks here with the message:

```
[UIImageAsset retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I have the image by the name `gradient-image` in `Images.xcassets`.
Honestly, I don't even know what other info would be relevant.

This happens on rare occasions, I cannot reproduce it consistently.
I've googled a bit, but not much results. So, I decided to create a question here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) on `UIImage imageNamed:`:

> You can not assume that this method is thread safe.

You must be on the main thread when loading `UIImage` objects. You can be on any thread when using them, but loading them requires the main thread.